Why many times $E= -{\rm grad} V$ does not give correct direction of the $E$?
Consider a point charge $Q$ at the origin, and consider two points, one on positive $z$ and one on negative $z$ direction, on the positive $z$ direction the point is located at $(0,0,z)$ and on negative $z$ direction at $(0,0,-z)$, thus, distance from origin is actually $z$,
The potential will be same for both two points, $V=kQ/|z|$, $k=1/4π\epsilon$, as $V=kQ/|r|$ but $|r|=|z|$,
Now, if we try to calculate electric field from $E=-\nabla V$, and taking gradient in Cartesian form,
We find that, for the point on positive z axis the field is obtained correctly,
$E=kQ/|z|^2$ in positive $z$ or $\hat{z}$ as it should be,
Now, if we similarly go for, the point on the negative z direction, we apply gradient, we arrive at the same results as above ! But it should point in the nagative $z$ direction as, for a (say it is positive) charge field lines goes away from the positive charge, hence in negative $z$ direction it should point in negative $z$ direction,
Now, to correct it where should I need to put a negative sign? In $V=kQ/|z|$ ?
But if I do this, then $V=kQ/|r|$ here $r$ is the distance and, here $|r|=|z|$ distance or magnitude of the position vector, If I would change $z$ to $-z$ , then it means that V depend upon sign of z, but it should not be the case, as electric field is central field and potential depends only upon distance mean only on $|z|$ and not its sign !
And I can't change the signs in gradient operator!,, If we think of substituting $-z$ at the end after finding field, $|z|^2$ would have no effect at all !
I know del operator tells something happening locally at the point of the intrest,
What is resolution to this !
Thank you, I hope my question is now clearer than before, Where I am mistaking?

Did you notice that your $V(z)$ is negative for $z<0$? Maybe you should recheck that. Or if you're limiting $z$ to be a distance, then the rest of your question putting in $z<0$ doesn't make sense.

This is a rather poor question. You correctly state that "the potential will be same for both two points" but your assertion that it is $kQ/z$ immediately afterwards directly contradicts that. The potential is $kQ/r$ and not $kQ/z$.

Suggest you reread the last part of my answer, starting "We reach the same result".

The notation you've used in your new first paragraph could still be misleading. '$z$, is usually reserved for a variable that can take negative or positive values according to position in relation to the origin. Therefore any point on the axis has co-ordinates (0,0, $z$). (0, 0, $-z$) is a sort of contradiction. All you need to do is call one of your points (0, 0, $a$) or (0, 0, $z_1$), say. The other will then be (0, 0, $-a$) or (0, 0, $-z_1$). The difference is that $a$ or $z_1$ is a particular value of $z$. So $z= a$ or $z=z_1$ at one of your points and $z= -a$ or $z=-z_1$ at the other.

This is my answer to your original question.
I'm afraid that you go wrong very near the beginning of your question. In your first paragraph you ask us to "consider two points, one on positive  and one on negative  direction, at the distance of magnitude ". '$z$' is here being used illogically to stand for two different quantities, the cartesian co-ordinate, which can take either positive or negative values, and its magnitude, which is always positive. In your second paragraph you use your second (magnitude) interpretation.
It would be better to denote the distance from the origin by another letter; $r$ is the usual choice.
We then have $$\frac{dV}{dr}=-\frac{kQ}{r^2}\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{so}\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{grad}\ V = -\frac{kQ}{r^2}\mathbf{\hat r}\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \ \ \textbf {E} = \frac{kQ}{r^2}\bf \hat r$$
Thus $\textbf E$ points in the direction of increasing $r$.
We reach the same result if we carefully use the cartesian co-ordinate, $z$. We must write the potential as $$V=\frac{kQ}{|z|}.$$
Then
$$\frac{dV}{d|z|}=-\frac{kQ}{|z|^2}=-\frac{kQ}{z^2}.$$ $$\text{So if}\ z>0\ \ \ \frac{dV}{dz}=-\frac{kQ}{z^2}\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \text {grad}\ V=-\frac{kQ}{z^2}\mathbf {\hat z}.$$
$$\text{But if}\ z<0\ \ \ \frac{dV}{dz}=\frac{kQ}{z^2}\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \text {grad}\ V=\frac{kQ}{z^2}\mathbf {\hat z}$$
From this follows the reversal of $\mathbf E$ at the origin. [You will have noted that $\mathbf{\hat z}$ points in the same direction in space (that of increasing z) whether $z<0$ or $z>0$.]

Okay, but What this is not directly apparent, If we put z hat while applying gradient, that's what concerns me the most!

I've expanded my answer to try to clear up your difficulty.

Okay, Got it, Thank you, I will be careful of this reversal of direction at the origin

You have not correctly used the unit vector nor gradient.
$$ V= \frac{1}{r}$$
$$-\nabla V = \frac{1}{r^2} \hat r$$
Which is the correct field direction for all valid points in space
You need to use the correct field and not zhat, employing the spherical gradient
This  radial unit vector ensures the correct direction for all points
